# Eclipse Fortran project directory structure

Tags: eclipse, makefile, fortran, fortran90

When I create a Fortran project by Eclipse,
it includes `bin` and `src` directories.

The automatically created `Makefile` has a rule that compiles `test.f90` in `src` and its runnable is written in `bin`.

I am a pretty new to Fortran. 
What if `test.f90` is supposed to be just an object which is required to compile an executable file, where should the object file, say `test.o`, be put? and when `test.f90` has a module inside, where should the module `test.mod` be output? `mod` at the same level as `src` and `bin`. or `share`, `lib`?

In that case, when I should separate all intermediate file in several directories, are there any template `Makefile`?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of Fortran project you created. If you created a Makefile project, you have full control/responsibility for where files are located. It appears to create a `src` and `bin` directory but beyond that, it looks like you can put other files like `*.mod` and `*.o` wherever you want. I'm not sure what the convention is for Fortran Makefile projects.

I prefer to avoid using Fortran Makefile projects because I have zero desire to manually sort out dependencies and targets with Makefiles, but that's a personal preference; if you're familiar with make and need the fine control it gives you, this is a reasonable choice. Just starting out with a Fortran Makefile project seems really painful unless you already know make.

A simpler, though less obvious to choose *"File | New | Fortran Project | Others"* when creating a Fortran project, then select the compiler and what you want to build. An example is *"Executable (Gnu Fortran on Linux/*nix)"* for building an executable with gfortran on a unix/linux-like system. Build targets include executables, static libraries, and shared libraries, each using gfortran, ifort, and a few other compilers, on Windows, OSX, or linux/Unix.

The `src` and `bin` directories are not automatically created but Makefiles are managed by Eclipse. Eclipse will automatically create a directory like `Debug` or `Debug_Intel64` and place executables, `*.o`, and `*.mod` files within it. If you make your own `src` directory, object files will be placed under `Debug/src` but the executables and module files will be under `Debug`. This directory name changes if you create a Release build configuration (Debug is the default).

By default, Eclipse puts all new source files in the project root but you can create Fortran source folders and organize your project however you want. The downside of automatic build management is that Eclipse is really only set up to build one thing, so if your project contains multiple executables (e.g. separate unit test, utilities, etc.) you need to manually build with make, CMake, etc.

Eclipse takes some getting used to, but integration with Mercurial is pretty good, and the Photran plugin (part of the Parallel Tools Project) helps with source templates, code analysis & Fortran refactoring tools, and a reasonably decent UI for configuring the compiler (at least for ifort on Linux). Plus it's cross-platform and works with a lot of other languages so it's far from the worst choice, especially if you're using Photran.

If you're not sold on Eclipse, I'd look at some less heavyweight options. Eclipse can be a pain some times and you might find a better IDE for what you're doing. OTOH, Eclipse works fine and the Photran plugin has some really nice features.

Answer (score -3):

For fortran beginners the best IDE is [codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads)

download the binaries with Mingw fortran compiler.

As your requirement it puts all your ***.mod*** and **.o** files to **obj** folder and **executables** in **bin** folder and **source** files are just used from the **directory where they are**.

Comment: Noting that the OP specifically asked about Eclipse, it's not clear how advice about Code::Blocks is relevant. It may be a fine IDE but you're answering a different question than the one that was asked.